# audio doesn't play when running program on startup

Tags: boot, audio

I have a python code that runs an mp3 file. It works perfectly when I run it through python 3.5.3 shell on my pi-top,
and I also managed to make the program run on startup, but then everything works except the audio file.

I have a feeling it relates to the fact that in the begining of the file I import some stuff (that I found on another manual).

here is my code:

```
import time
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os
DEBUG = 1
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

def RCtime (RCpin):
    reading = 0
    GPIO.setup(RCpin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(RCpin, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.1)

    GPIO.setup(RCpin, GPIO.IN)

    while (GPIO.input(RCpin) == GPIO.LOW):
        reading += 1
    return reading

toprint = 0
ledpin = 17
GPIO.setup(ledpin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(ledpin, GPIO.LOW)
blabla = 0

while True:
    var1 = RCtime(27)
    if (var1 < 4000) & toprint:
        print(var1)
        print("open")
        os.system('mpg123 -q yarimmp3.mp3 &')
        GPIO.output(ledpin, GPIO.LOW)
        toprint = 0

     if (var1 > 15000) & (toprint==0):
        print(var1)
        print("closed")
        GPIO.output(ledpin, GPIO.HIGH)
        toprint = 1
```

Thank you!

Comment: What operating system you are using? Raspbian? How do you run the program at startup? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Add the full path to mpg123 and the mp3 file.

```
os.system('/usr/bin/mpg123 -q /home/pi/yarimmp3.mp3 &')
```

Applications run as root user rather than pi user at startup.